Spring ldapTemplate search() doesn't return dn attribute
I've got a fairly straight forward program that performs an LDAP search based on a CN and maps all the returned attributes, here's the program:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.query.ConditionCriteria;
import org.springframework.ldap.query.ContainerCriteria;
import static org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQueryBuilder.query;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource;

public class LDAPSearchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldaps://localhost:636");
        contextSource.setUserDn("");
        contextSource.setPassword("");
        contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(false);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);

        ConditionCriteria condition
                = query()
                        .base("baseDNValue")
                        .where("cn");

        ContainerCriteria filter = condition.is("cnValue");
        List<Map<String, List<Object>>> results = ldapTemplate.search(
                filter,
                new DefaultAttributesMapper());
        for (Map<String, List<Object>> groupSearchResult : results) {
            for (String attributeName : groupSearchResult.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("\t%s", attributeName));
                for (Object attributeValue : groupSearchResult.get(attributeName)) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("\t\t%s", attributeValue == null ? null : attributeValue.toString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static class DefaultAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper<Map<String, List<Object>>> {

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<Object>> mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
            Map<String, List<Object>> mappedAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> attributesEnumeration = attributes.getAll();
            while (attributesEnumeration.hasMore()) {
                Attribute nextAttribute = attributesEnumeration.next();
                mappedAttributes.put(nextAttribute.getID(), new ArrayList<>());
                NamingEnumeration attributeValuesEnumeration = nextAttribute.getAll();
                while (attributeValuesEnumeration.hasMore()) {
                    Object nextAttributeValue = attributeValuesEnumeration.next();
                    mappedAttributes.get(nextAttribute.getID()).add(nextAttributeValue);
                }
            }
            return mappedAttributes;
        }
    }
}

For some reason the attribute dn is not included in the return attributes list, but every other one is (as far as I can see).  When I do an equivalent search using ldapsearch, the dn attribute is returned in the result.  Any insight as to why I'm not able to retrieve the dn back from the Java code would be helpful.

Entry DN is not an attribute. It only happens to be formatted like an attribute in LDIF-format text output, but really is a separate 'object name' field in the actual LDAP response, and is usually exposed through a separate variable in LDAP client libraries.
In Spring LDAP, it seems you need to use the .getDn() method of the returned result.
